# How can be column incluted into rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, libreoffice-calc, table-of-contents

There is the table in MS Excel or LO Calc.

[image: from this]

How can be it converted to this view of the table?

[image: to this]

The transformation using links (within the same table) to the initial version is allowed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? searching for "unpivot an excel table" should lead you to many answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft 365, you can come close with:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(
    TEXTJOIN(
        "|",
        ,
        SORT(
            TOCOL(
                TOROW(A2:A4) & "~" &
                    TOCOL(B1:D1)
            )
        ) & "~" & TOCOL(B2:D4)
    ),
    "~",
    "|"
)
```

We use the `TOROW` and `TOCOL` functions to create a Cartesian Product of the rows and columns, connecting each crossjoin by a delimiter. We then join the resultant single column with a different delimiter. Finally, we split the rows and columns using the `TEXTSPLIT` function.

The Formula Evaluation tool will help you see what's going on.

But, to not show the "duplicates" in the first column of output, you need to use conditional formatting using a formula to see if the content matches that of the row above. If it does, then format the font color to be the same as the background color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it only at MS Excel 365, but not at MS Excel 2013 or earlier?

Comment: @Imyaf That is why I wrote *"...If you have Microsoft 365..."*. Your tags did not indicate any version restrictions. To do this in an earlier version, I suggest Power Query (Excel 2010 or later) or VBA. And it would also depend on whether you are using Windows or MAC.